# why changed function in sequelize.js is not working in afterValidate hook?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, hook, reset-password

```js
hooks: {
  afterValidate: async function (user, next) {
   if (!user.changed("password")) {
     next()
   };
   const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
   user.password = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt);
 }
},
```

When i try to run this code it throws an error saying next is not a function. And if i don't use changed function whenever i try to reset my password it rehash it. So what is wrong in my code and what do you suggest about the solution. Thank u. I just want to do it [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hpPm.png)

Answer (score 1):

I had two problems - 1: why my reset password was not working properly , 2: why it throws an error about next is not a function.
So, here I found the solutions after some debugging and some help from the comment of Mr.Anatoly.

solution of 1: I need to use `beforeSave` hook for the reset password to work.
solution of 2: I need to call empty return to go to the next hook.

Complete solution of the problem looks like this :

```
beforeSave: async function(user)  {
    if (!user.changed("password")) { 
        return;
    } else {
        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
        user.password = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hooks do not have `next` as a function (like in Express.js routes), the second parameter is `options` that look like this:

```js
  /**
   * An array of strings. All properties that are in this array will not be validated
   */
  skip?: string[];
  /**
   * An array of strings. Only the properties that are in this array will be validated
   */
  fields?: string[];
```

To go to the next validation hook you just need to call `return` to exit from the current hook.

```js
hooks: {
  afterValidate: async function (user, next) {
   if (!user.changed("password")) {
     return;
   };
   const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
   user.password = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt);
 }
},
```

Comment: Thank you, sir. And also one of my problem was my reset password was not working. I found the solution , i was hashing my password after validation. i just changed the hook to beforeSave and it worked. Please upvote my question so if someone has the same problem they can find the solution here. Thanks again.